# Scala constructor

Tags: scala

What is the equivalent of the below Java code in Scala:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Bool {

 private boolean door;
 Random random = new Random();

 Bool() {
  this.door = random.nextBoolean();
 }
}
```

So when a new Bool object is created, the door variable will automatically get a random Boolean value.

Answer (score 11):

In Scala, the body of the class is equivalent to the methods invoked by a constructor in Java.  Hence your class would look something like the following:

```
import java.util.Random

class Bool {
    private val random = new Random
    private val door = random.nextBoolean()

    ... // method definitions, etc.
}
```

(note that to be picky, since you didn't declare your Java variables `final`, one could argue that the fields should be `var`s here instead.  Additionally, your `random` field is package-protected which looks like an oversight, and would be rendered in Scala as `protected[pkgName]` where `pkgName` is the name of the most specific component of the class' package.)

Answer (score 5):

Here is my take:

```
case class MyBool(door: Boolean = Random.nextBoolean)
```

This leaves open the possibility to create a new instance of `MyBool` with a certain door value, e.g.:

```
val x1 = MyBool() // random door
val x2 = MyBool(true) // door set explicitly
```

Since there can only be two different door values, it would make sense to use static objects instead, like this:

```
sealed trait MyBool {
  def door:Boolean
}
object MyBool {
  case object True extends MyBool {
    def door = true
  }

  case object False extends MyBool {
    def door = false
  }

  def apply:MyBool = if(Random.nextBoolean) True else False
}
```

Usage:

```
val x1 = MyBool() // random door value
val x2 = MyBool.True // explicit door value
```

Comment: +1 modulo the obsolete `case` and missing `val`/`var` in line 2.

Comment: Is it not possible to do everything in one line? Like case class MyBool(var door: Boolean = Random.nextBoolean)..So, unless we give it a value while instantiating, it is Random.nexBoolean ? Or am I talking nonsense?

Comment: @Raphael: No, the `case` is definitely needed there. Every argument of a case class constructor is automatically also a public `val`. Also, it adds a lot of goodies automatically, like reasonable implementations of `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString`, as well as companion `apply` and `unapply` methods. So, it should better not be left out.

Comment: @blackened: This is exactly the case class that I wrote. In a case class, unless you explicitly declare a parameter as a `var`, it will automatically be a `val`. All constructor parameters of case classes are `val`s by default. In addition to that, case classes also provide a lot of other useful stuff. You can look it up, it's really cool.

Comment: @Madoc None of which can not be coded by hand when needed. I disagree with using it as default as it blows up (compiled) code complexity maybe unnecessary.

Comment: Why do you create this class instead of using the primitive Boolean?

Answer (score 3):

The closer scala code should be:

```
class Bool {
  var random = new Random
  private var door = random.nextBoolean
}
```

Even if the public `random` field does not look as a good idea.